# Change in generic behavior between 3.0.1 and 3.1.3

Tags: typescript

I have the following code, which works in TypeScript 3.0.1 but gives compile errors in 3.1.3. If possible, I'd like to know what changed in 3.1.+ that makes the code invalid, or if this may be a compiler bug.

```
export interface Entity {
    id: number | string;
}

export type IdOf<E extends Entity> = E['id'];

export interface EntityState<E extends Entity> {
    ids: IdOf<E>[];
    entities: { [key: string]: E, [key: number]: E };
}


export function getAllEntities<E extends Entity>(state: EntityState<E>): E[] {
    const { ids, entities } = state;
    return ids.map(id => entities[id]);
}

export function getEntity<E extends Entity>(id: IdOf<E>, state: EntityState<E>): E | undefined {
    const { ids, entities } = state;

    if (!ids.includes(id)) {
        return undefined;
    }

    return entities[id];
}
```

As I said, it compiles fine in 3.0.1, but in 3.1.3 I get the following errors:

```
BUILD ERROR
projects/entity/src/lib/entity-state.utils.ts(13,5): error TS2322: Type '{ [key: string]: E; [key: number]: E; }[E["id"]][]' is not assignable to type 'E[]'.
  Type '{ [key: string]: E; [key: number]: E; }[E["id"]]' is not assignable to type 'E'.
    Type 'Entity' is not assignable to type 'E'.
projects/entity/src/lib/entity-state.utils.ts(23,5): error TS2322: Type '{ [key: string]: E; [key: number]: E; }[E["id"]]' is not assignable to type 'E | undefined'.
  Type 'Entity' is not assignable to type 'E'.
    Type '{ [key: string]: E; [key: number]: E; }[E["id"]]' is not assignable to type 'E'.
      Type 'Entity' is not assignable to type 'E'.
```

The two errors correspond to the two functions' return statements, respectively.

Edit. For completeness, I'll just mention that I intend for users to create subinterfaces of `Entity` and `EntityState` for their domain types, overriding `id` to be a more restrictive type. This is why the `IdOf` type is important. E.g.,

```
interface Task extends Entity {
    id: string;
    due: Date;
    title: string;
}

interface TaskState extends EntityState<Task> {
    // Inherits EntityState#ids as string[]
    currentTask?: string;
}
```

Comment: Quite frankly this seems like either an undocumented breaking change, or a regression. I would suggest you submit it on GitHub and see what the team says.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I created https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27895, we'll see what happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `type` to `interface` fixes the problem, type doesn't support extending, always use `interface` if you need inheritance to work, the fact that it was working earlier is confusing, maybe they added more strict rules to generic types checking

```
export interface Entity {
    id: number | string;
}

export type IdOf<E extends Entity> = E['id'];

export interface EntityState<E extends Entity> {
    ids: IdOf<E>[];
    entities: { [key: string]: E, [key: number]: E };
}


export function getAllEntities<E extends Entity>(state: EntityState<E>): E[] {
    const { ids, entities } = state;
    return ids.map(id => entities[id]) as E[];
}

export function getEntity<E extends Entity>(id: IdOf<E>, state: EntityState<E>): E | undefined {
    const { ids, entities } = state;

    if (!ids.includes(id)) {
        return undefined;
    }

    return entities[id] as E;
}
```

Comment: This `export interface IdOf<E extends Entity> = E['id'];` is not valid typescript syntax. Only a type alias can use `=`

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited my answer, since the issue is in the `EntityState.ids` and `E` always extends `Entity`, I simply changed ids in EntityState to directly inherit the type from Entity

Comment: This is not quite the same. A subinterface of `Entity` may override `id` to be a more restrictive type, and `IdOf<E>` would reflect that.

Comment: It took me a long while to research, I edited my answer with a quick fix, using `as` operator, I tried to update to 3.1 myself and it's unstable and raised a lot of issues, soon after I downgraded to 3.0.3 so I can get my code working, if you don't wanna downgrade then use `as` operator as a quick solution until they fix this issue or they tell us how to deal with that in documentation

Comment: I think casting is probably the only way to handle this in 3.1.+. I'll mark this answer as accepted tonight unless someone comes up with a better workaround.